# Как правильно написать указанное предложение?

Tags: грамматика

> Глухие считают, что те, кто танцует, сумасшедшие.

1. Мне кажется, что надо тире перед "сумасшедшие"
2. Мне кажется, что правильно - "танцуют"

Answer (score 1):

**Глухие считают, что те, кто танцует, сумасшедшие.**

Нет причин для внесения изменений.

1) Именная часть сказуемого выражена прилагательным, а подлежащее – местоимением. **Обычно в этом случае тире не ставится**. Для авторского тире (паузы) также нет оснований (при отсутствии тире логическое ударение смещено на сказуемое).

2) **Кто танцует/танцуют.** Возможны обе формы, но мн. число подчеркивает множественность производителей действия, а здесь рассматривается **индивидуальная оценка.**

Розенталь, §187. Сказуемое при подлежащем-местоимении вопросительном, относительном, неопределенном, отрицательном.
 [http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#з_05](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_05)